# Whenever + tense

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I was taking an English test, and the sentence was :

> The barrage would be used whenever an exceptional tide ... forecast.

a) was
b) is

and I don't remember c) and d).

I went for b), however the answer indicated by the website was a). It just seems weird to me to say "was" in this sentence, could you confirm that the real answer is "was"?

Comment: Normally, it *would* be idiomatic to use ***was*** for your context -
 where *would be used* specifically refers to (habitual) action in the ***past***. But I think if ***would*** referred to a hypothetical future (as in an engineer explaining what his barrage would be used for, ***if*** the city council backed his proposal to build it), it wouldn't be ridiculous to use ***is***.

Comment: I wish I could back myself up with citations and make an answer out of is, but let me give two examples, "He would eat lots of candy when he was younger" and "He would eat lots of candy when he is younger". Do you see how the latter sentence sounds wrong?

Comment: There was a barrage across the Elbonus in the late 20th Century. The barrage would be used whenever an exceptional tide was forecast. But it failed in 1986 due to rising sea-levels. // A barrage across the Freedonus has been suggested. The barrage would be used whenever an exceptional tide is forecast.

Comment: @Dispenser As FumbleFingers's comment suggests, the distinction is really between your first example and something like "He would eat less candy when he is older". *Was* suits the former and *is* suits the latter.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I understand now. What I didn't understand was that the sentence is at the past tense. I thought the barrage was still used.

Answer (score -1):

*Whenever* signals the habitual aspect, i.e., an action repeated either still in the present or no longer. In your case, the barrage is apparently no longer in use, so the first clause is cast in the [*past habitual*.](https://www.thoughtco.com/habitual-past-grammar-1690829)

The *is + something*, regardless of the rest of the verb phrase, must be in some form of the present tense, but since all this repeated action took place in the past, that choice can be readily eliminated.

For the clause after *whenever*, the vast majority of writers will use the simple past:

> The barrage would be used whenever an exceptional tide *was* forecast.

A Google [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whenever%20he%20would%20go%2Cwhenever%20he%20went&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhenever%20he%20would%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhenever%20he%20went%3B%2Cc0) querying for *whenever he would go* and *whenever he went* yielded only a few hits for extending the use of the past habitual after *whenever*, even when the *whenever*-clause [opens the sentence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Whenever%20he%20would%20go%2CWhenever%20he%20went&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhenever%20he%20would%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhenever%20he%20went%3B%2Cc0).

You can read more about the various ways English signals the habitual aspect [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/habitual-past-grammar-1690829).